# functions.php file unable to filter parent theme

Tags: wordpress

I am going through a tutorial to create modular css in wordpress at the following link:

http://themeshaper.com/2009/04/30/modular-css-wordpress-child-themes/

When I use style.css to import css files from the library it works. 
Here is the code in style.css in the child theme:

**style.css**

```
/* CSS Document */
/*
Theme Name: Chiron
Description: Child theme of thematic
Template: thematic
*/

/* Using @import, we can borrow style sheets from the Parent Theme */

/* Reset the browser defaults */
@import url('../thematic/library/styles/reset.css');

/* Apply default typography */
@import url('../thematic/library/styles/typography.css');

/* Add WordPress image styles */
@import url('../thematic/library/styles/images.css');

/* Add a basic layout */
@import url('../thematic/library/layouts/2c-l-fixed.css');

/* Start with some default styles */
@import url('../thematic/library/styles/18px.css');
```

But when I am removing all the imports from style.css and using functions.php inside my child theme directory to load the css files it is not working.

**functions.php**

```
<?php

function childtheme_create_stylesheet() {
    $templatedir = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
    $stylesheetdir = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $templatedir ?>/library/styles/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $templatedir ?>/library/styles/typography.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $templatedir ?>/library/styles/images.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $templatedir ?>/library/layouts/2c-l-fixed.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $templatedir ?>/library/styles/18px.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $stylesheetdir ?>/style.css" />

    <?php    
}
add_filter('thematic_create_stylesheet', 'childtheme_create_stylesheet');

?>
```

Can any one please suggest where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Be careful when following extremely old tutorials, and don't forget to Google your problem before you post a question on Stack Overflow. That tutorial is over 6 years old, and [the very first Google result for `thematic_create_stylesheet`](https://www.google.com.au/#q=thematic_create_stylesheet) explains that this hook was removed in Thematic 1.0 (over three years ago), and you should instead be using `wp_enqueue_style`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the correct method to add in stylesheets (and scripts) with the relevant functions:

```
// Enqueue Scripts
function my_scripts() {
  wp_register_style( 'main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css');
  wp_register_style( 'anotherfile', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'main' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'anotherfile' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Especially as you have a lot of files this will allow you to make use of something like W3TC and combine and minimise the files.

You can add this code into your child themes functions.php file.

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style and https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
href="<?php echo $templatedir; ?>/library/styles/reset.css
```

instead of

```
href="<?php echo $templatedir ?>/library/styles/reset.css
```

But be ensure that `$templatedir` and `$stylesheetdir` are giving you the right directory.

Also use

`add_action( 'admin_init', 'childtheme_create_stylesheet' );`

instead of

```
add_filter('thematic_create_stylesheet', 'childtheme_create_stylesheet');
```

it is highly recommended to use wordpress default function. You can visit here for this :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
1. if you want to you use **parent** theme url  :

> get_template_directory_uri();

2. if you want to you use **child** theme url  :

> get_stylesheet_directory_uri();

**In style.css(child theme):**

```
/*
Theme Name: twentyfifteen-child
Template: twentyfifteen

*/
```

**In Function.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    echo  get_template_directory_uri();
    echo  get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
```

**Try this:**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    echo  get_template_directory_uri();
    echo  get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );    
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-stylereset', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/styles/reset.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-styletypo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/styles/typography.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-styleimges', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/styles/images.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style2c', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/layouts/2c-l-fixed.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style18px', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/styles/18px.css' );

}
```